# How to use json_decode with Smarty

Tags: php, smarty, template-engine

Its my first time working with [Smarty Template Engine](http://www.smarty.net/) and I am having troubles translating the following PHP json_decode statement into a Smarty friendly code. The output is an array since I use the TRUE in the json_decode.

```
$itemArray = json_decode($dni-content-slider-id-prefix-saved-content-picker-item- . $promos, true)
```

I've tried

```
{ assign var  $itemArray = value=$dni-content-slider-id-prefix-saved-content-picker-item-|cat:$promos|json_decode}
```

But it doesnt really work. any suggestions?

Comment: What does "doesn't really work" mean? That it returns something, but not what you're expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much everything in that line of Smarty is wrong; let's go through in order:

```
{ assign
```

Don't put a space between the `{` and the Smarty tag; if Smarty 3's ["auto-literal" feature](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.escaping.tpl) is switched on, it will assume that's a literal `{` not a Smarty tag.

```
var  $itemArray =
```

You seem to be mixing two different functions here. The Smarty [`{assign}` function](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl) takes the form `{assign var=some_name value=$some_value}`. Note that the `var` parameter is the *name* of the variable to assign, so does not need a `$`.

Smarty 3 also has a PHP-style ["short-form assign"](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.builtin.functions.tpl#language.function.shortform.assign), which looks like `{$some_name=$some_value}` (complete with `$`, but no `assign` keyword).

```
value=$dni-content-slider-id-prefix-saved-content-picker-item-|cat:$promos
```

This will take the content of the variable `$dni-content-slider-id-prefix-saved-content-picker-item-` treat it as a string, and add the content of the variable `$promos` (also treated as a string) to the end of it. Looking again, I see that that is also what your PHP code does, but it seems a very odd thing to do, since the first variable would have to be something like `"{'foo':'bar',"` and the second something like `"'baz':'quux'}"`. Why would you ever have variables like that?

*Based on the PHP code being the same, I'm going to assume this paragraph was wrong on my part* <s>What I suspect you want is a variable variable name (a different variable when the code runs); there are ways to do that, but this isn't one of them. It's also generally a really bad idea; if you want lots of similar variables which you can select from at run-time, put them in an associative array, and index something like `$dni-content-slider-id-prefix-saved-content-picker-items[$promos]`.</s>

```
|json_decode}
```

Finally, the part actually related to your question. You point out that in PHP, you pass the optional `true` parameter to the `json_decode` function, but in this Smarty code, you are not doing so. This can be easily done by adding `:true` on the end, as in `{assign var=itemArray value=$jsonString|json_decode:true}`.